# Phantom JS not downloading webpage as html for certain website but other sites work

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm using a github project to download a webpage as html and save as pdf.

I'm calling javascript file that uses phantom js to do this. Other pages work perfect but my target url on atlassian does not work. I get a blank pdf with no data and when I save as html same it's a blank webpage

Does anybody know why or how I could fix this problem?

the target url is
https://blackdogs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOR/overview/

link to repo is
https://github.com/morninj/web2pdf

screenhot.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create()
var system = require('system')
var address = system.args[1];
var output = system.args[2];
var fs = require('fs');
page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 702 }; // Default on my 13" MacBook
page.customHeaders = {
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
};
    
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
      console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
    
        phantom.exit();
 } else {
       window.setTimeout(function () 
         page.render(output);
         fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
    
         phantom.exit();
         }, 10000);
       }
   });
```

web2pdf.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import call
import argparse
import sys
import os
import time
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', help='The URL of a single page ' \
    + 'to download.')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--filename', help='The name of a file containing ' \
    + 'multiple URLs to download. Put each URL on a new line.')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='If you\'re archiving just one ' \
    + 'page, this is the name of the output file. The default is ' \
    + 'archive.pdf.')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', help='The name of the directory ' \
    + 'to store multiple archives. The default is "archives."')
args = parser.parse_args()

def web2pdf():
    if args.url and not args.filename:
        # Save a single URL
        output_filename = 'archive.pdf'
        if args.output: output_filename = args.output
        time.sleep(4)
        make_screenshot(args.url, output_filename)
    elif args.filename and not args.url:
        # Save multiple URLs
        # Create the archives directory
        archives_directory = 'archives'
        if args.directory: archives_directory = args.directory
        call(['mkdir', archives_directory])
        # Process each line in the input file
        with open(args.filename) as f:
            counter = 0
            for line in f:
                print ('Archiving %s...' % line.strip())
                # Generate filenames: 01.pdf, 02.pdf, ..., 99.pdf
                counter = counter + 1
                output_filename = str(counter)
                if counter < 10: output_filename = '0' + output_filename
                output_filename = archives_directory + '/' \
                    + output_filename + '.pdf'
                make_screenshot(line.strip(), output_filename)
    else:
        # No URL or list of URLs provided
        print ('Please give either a URL or a filename containing a list of URLs.')
        sys.exit()
    print ('Done.')

def make_screenshot(url, filename):
    # Call PhantomJS and suppress its output
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as fnull: 
        call(
            ['phantomjs', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/screenshot.js', url, filename],
            stdout=fnull,
            stde
```

Comment: The page is dynamic. None of the content is there until it's added by javascript after the render. If you right-click the page and do "Save As", you'll see all of the initial markup. Pretty sure phantom won't be able to handle this.

Comment: I thought phantom js was a lib for dealing with JS content sites no?

Comment: Perhaps, but I haven't seen a working example of a fully SPA app. Note that phantom is largely abandoned. There are some later commits by the community, but not many. The engine is pretty outdated at this point, not supporting features used commonly now by modern frameworks.

Not really a solution to the question as posed, but you might want to try https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer which is a driver for headless chrome.

Comment: @erich2k8 Phantomjs is also a headless chrome so any solution that works with puppeteer would also work with phantomjs and any issues faced by phantomjs probably would also be an issue in puppeteer

Comment: @siebetman, Phantomjs was webkit. I'm not sure how many SPA sites work on 5 year old webkit but I would guess not many.